# var/log filing up entire space

Tags: ubuntu, logging

I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS, suddenly the var/log folder is increasing constantly and is filling up the entire space, and I have to clear it multiple times, if anyone has ever experienced this before and knows the solution, please help.

Answer (score 0):

`logrotate` might help with this depending on how quickly your logs are filling up. See this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-logfiles-with-logrotate-on-ubuntu-16-04

The other thing you should do is to analyse the logs to see why they are growing so quickly. Probably worth checking it hasn't been hacked too.